# How to send SOAP request via Postman

Tags: web-services, soap, postman

I'm trying to send a SOAP request via the Postman chrome extension. My request body looks like this in Postman:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://partnerapi.somewhere.com/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:GetCustomers>
      <GetCustomersRequest>
        <APIKey>SECRET</APIKey>
        <PartnerKey></PartnerKey>    
        <SearchText></SearchText>
        <ItemsPerPage>50</ItemsPerPage>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
        <Fields></Fields>
        <OrderBy></OrderBy>
      </GetCustomersRequest> 
    </ns1:GetCustomers>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Edit:

Clicking the `Generate Code` button in Postman provides the following snippet:

```
POST /PartnerAPI.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: http://partnerapi.somewhere.com/GetCustomers
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 1af78251-9d36-0c94-d0e3-21f7e37ffc41
```

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://partnerapi.somewhere.com/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:GetCustomers>
      <GetCustomersRequest>
        <APIKey>SECRET</APIKey>
        <PartnerKey></PartnerKey>    
        <SearchText></SearchText>
        <ItemsPerPage>50</ItemsPerPage>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
        <Fields></Fields>
        <OrderBy></OrderBy>
      </GetCustomersRequest> 
    </ns1:GetCustomers>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have the web service running in Visual Studio and I have a breakpoint set in the web method which is being hit so the request is reaching the endpoint.

The web method signature looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public CustomersObject GetCustomers(RequestObjects.GetCustomersRequest GetCustomersRequest)
```

But the `GetCustomersRequest` parameter is always NULL.

The `GetCustomersRequest` class looks like this:

```
public class GetCustomersRequest {
    public string APIKey;
    public string PartnerKey;
    public string SearchText;
    public int ItemsPerPage = 50;
    public int PageNumber = 1;

    public string Fields;
    public string OrderBy;
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You showed your request body, but what about the remainder of your request! In Postman, if you click on "Generate Code" and paste that here, it might be more helpful.

Comment: @SiKing I added the snippet produced by "Generate Code" button as suggested

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turned out to be quite straight forward in the end. All I did was browse to the web service, which then lists the endpoints available. Then clicked on the `GetCustomers` link. Which shows an example of the XML required. I then used that as the basis for the request body in Postman (You may notice that some of the `namespaces` are different from my original attempt).

Clicking the `Generate Code` button in Postman produces the following:

```
POST /PartnerAPI.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:53355
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://partnerapi.somewhere.com/GetCustomers
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 914d2152-9063-ff57-91a0-e567714c2d44
```

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCustomers xmlns="http://partnerapi.somewhere.com/">
      <GetCustomersRequest>
        <APIKey>SECRET</APIKey>
        <SearchText></SearchText>
        <ItemsPerPage>10</ItemsPerPage>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
        <Fields></Fields>
        <OrderBy></OrderBy>
      </GetCustomersRequest>
    </GetCustomers>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Which successfully reaches the endpoint but this time the `GetCustomersRequest` parameter is populated correctly!